# Accessing MemoryMappedFiles in Unity

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine, memory-mapped-files

I need to use the `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles` namespace but keep getting complaints from Unity saying that the namespace `MemoryMappedFiles` does not exist in `System.IO`. I guess that's because Unity uses a .NET 2.0 like mono implementation, which does not include this namespace. I also tried to create a *Plugins* directory (*Assets/Scripts/Plugins*) and copied `System.Core.dll` (from */mono/2.0*) to that directory. However, MemoryMappedFile still cannot be found when I try to use the following function in one of my Scripts:

```
static object ReadObjectFromMMF(string mmfFile)
{
    // Get a handle to an existing memory mapped file
    using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(mmfFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        // Create a view accessor from which to read the data
        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor mmfReader = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
        {
            // Create a data buffer and read entire MMF view into buffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[mmfReader.Capacity];
            mmfReader.ReadArray<byte>(0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Convert the buffer to a .NET object
            return ByteArrayToObject(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another way to access a MemoryMappedFile from Unity?

**EDIT:**

Actually, I simply want to transfer data from another C# Application to my Unity App. It does not necessarily have to be a MemoryMappedFile. I am just looking for any simple way to perform Inter-Process-Communication with Unity. I searched in the Unity Documentation for a recommended way for performing IPC with Unity (e.g. sharing an object between a Unity App and another App). As Unity uses an old version of Mono (i.e. the .NET 2.0 like mono implementation), I could not find a way to do that. It would be great if someone could show me where I can find some information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying a recent System.dll into your Assets folder, not Plugins.

Core .dll files can be accessed from there.

Comment: What do you mean by _recent_? I just copied the `System.dll` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0` into my Assets folder but I still get the error saying that the type of namespace 'MemoryMappedFile' could not be found.

Comment: You need to ensure its a .NET 3.5 and lower compliant assembly, .NET 4 assemblies won't work as the compiled code is not compatible with what unity supports (its not backward compatible).

Comment: If you have unity Pro, you can try native API's;
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

Answer (score -1):

You may try `CreateFileMapping`, `OpenFileMapping`,`MapViewOfFile` from `kernel32.dll`